# How do I make the timespan shown by org agenda start yesterday?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

If today is Thursday, I want the agenda to be from Wednesday (yesterday) through next Tuesday.

When I set `org-agenda-day` to `"-1d"`, it shows the full week (starting Monday) that contains yesterday. I want it to start yesterday, even if yesterday isn't Monday.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If `org-agenda-start-on-weekday` is set to an integer (by default it's set to 1, corresponding to Monday), and `org-agenda-span` is set to *either* `'week` or `7`, org will always start the agenda on the day specified by `org-agenda-start-on-weekday`.

So to always start yesterday, you must set `org-agenda-start-day` to `"-1d"` *and* do one of the following:

1. Set `org-agenda-start-on-weekday` to `nil`. Then, the first day of the agenda will be determined by `org-agenda-start-day`.
2. Set `org-agenda-span` to a value that isn't `'week`. For example, setting it to `5` will show five days, and then it will respect `org-agenda-start-day`.

I recommend doing both, in case you decide you want to show a full week. Here's code to show five days starting yesterday:

```el
(setq org-agenda-start-day "-1d")
(setq org-agenda-span 5)
(setq org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
```